# Linux touchscreen -- file menu item selected but not clicked on tap

Tags: linux-mint, menu, touch-screen

I'm having a weird issue with my new touchscreen-enabled laptop on Linux Mint 19. The laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 510 (AMD 9410 cpu)

For some, but not all programs, opening the file menu and tapping on an item seems to simply select that item, but not actually successfully click it.

For example, if I open `xreader` (Linux Mint's native pdf viewer app), I can successfully tap on `File` and this will bring the file menu up, but then tapping on `Close` only highlights it, but doesn't actually select it to close the program.

This only happens with some programs but not others. For example, on Firefox, selecting the file menu and then closing works as expected and closes the browser.

Any ideas? I have also tried two-finger tapping to simulate a right-mouse click, but that seems to have the same issue (and is not that useful in any case, since the available space for tapping is usually too small for a two-finger tap anyway).

All other expected aspects of touchscreen functionality seem to work fine otherwise.

PS. I also have touchegg installed, which works as expected, and a scaled display via xrandr; however I have reproduced the above without these as well so I don't think they're related to the issue.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: @IporSircer Submitted https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/issues/267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in Gnome. It affects all programs that use libgtk-3.

See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/945

There is no simple solution at present.